# Raspberry Pi B+ not displaying screen

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, video, output

I recently bought Raspberry Pi B+ model, When I try to connect it with my LED TV(24 inch) using HDMI cable it's not displaying anything, showing as no signal.

I try to connect basic connectivity plugs like MicroSD, HDMI, Power Plug.

(I used RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy 2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian.img in my micro SD)
It's not showing any display(No Signal). Is there any thing I am missing or should I need to reset anything?.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the red LED shine/blink? I had similar problem, then I figured out, that I didn't have power connected right.

Comment: The Red LED is shine and Green LED is blinking correctly.

Comment: Once no signal in a similar situation was found 
to be due to the cheap HDMI cable. With the proper (and more expensive) one everything works fine.

Comment: I have 2 HDMI cables, both are working fine when I connected to my laptop and they are not displaying screen when I connected to RBP :( .

Comment: Have you tried running through the steps outlined here? http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#No_HDMI_output_at_all. Hope they help

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enough amperage in your power adaptor. Sometimes the Pi has enough power to compute, but somehow it's not enough to generate the signal.
The minimum amperage is `700 mA`

Answer (score 0):

Format and reinstall the newest Raspian. Ensure the display is connected since the first run. If you have usb devices such as keyboard and mouse, remove them prior to the first boot. 
If it does not work, make sure the Pi is able to display in another monitor or projector though.

Answer (score 0):

On my particular TV (brand is TCL), there are three HMDI inputs. When there is nothing plugged into the chosen input, I get 'No Signal'.

There seven menu selections when I press the 'Input' button:

- TV

  AV

  CMPT

  PC

  HDMI1

  HDMI2

  HDMI3

Do you have multiple HDMI inputs?

Comment: He mentions that a laptop works with the TV and HDMI cable, so input selection is probably not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to debug this will be to connect via serial to the pi to see what is going on.

I use a USB-UART adapter to connect to the pi serial console. On this link, [RPi Serial Connection](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection), you can see how to set up this. On this other link, [RPi Low-level peripherals](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals)
, you can find a description of the GPIO ports that may help you clarify where to connect you cables.

Once all is set, you can connect to your pi, using minicom for example

```
sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB1
```

where ttyUSB1 is your USB-UART device.

This will enable you to see the boot process of the pi and what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change config.txt file in /boot folder of your rootfs in pi??

if yes,
then put comment on all of them. and then start your pi again.

and also check your Pi B+ does it blinks??

if yes try to ssh from another machine.

and take a look on this http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=52309   It may help you

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the similar problem. In my case I had the **steady Red and Green light** glowing.
 if this is your case then the Raspberry could not detect your SD card, 
Please make sure the following.
1. your SD card has to be formatted before use.
2. DD command has to be targeting /dev/**mmcblk0** not mmcblk0p1.(p1 stands for its first partition)
So my DD command looks like follows,

```
sudo dd bs=16M if=/home/krishl/Study/RoseberryPi/**2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie-lite.img** of=**/dev/mmcblk0**
```

you can issue sync after the dd.

Ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md

Comment: I think the OP said that "*The Red LED is shine and Green LED is blinking correctly.*" So your point about a steady Green meaning a SD card was not detected - although true - is probably not the issue.  On the other hand depending on the number of blinks of that Green LED it may be that the card is not correctly formatted so that one of the files that need to be read during boot up may be closer to the mark. 8-)